Ballpark estimate number of US patents a given large technology company has obtained by buying them or acquiring their assignees?
I'd like to get a ballpark estimate for how many US patents that a given large technology company has obtained by buying them or acquiring their assignees rather than filing them themselves.
Just for example: the number of patents for which the current assignee is Applied Materials (AMAT, Santa Clara) but the original assignee was NOT AMAT nor a company owned by them at that time.
I'm not interested if they are currently active, the focus is on the approximate volume of patents acquired no matter what they did with them afterward.
Is this kind of search specifiable by publicly available sites like USPTO or Google?

Background: I'll be giving a presentation and suggesting that a reasonable exit strategy for a startup is acquisition - suggesting that companies will sometimes buy patents and perhaps their assignees as well just to make sure someone else doesn't have them, even in cases where they may not actually ultimately use the patents.
In other words, you don't have to make an overwhelmingly compelling argument that a startups IP is going to be incredibly lucrative in order for the acquisition exit strategy to be plausible.
So I'd like to show that companies X, Y and Z have bought "a lot" of patents that they, or companies they owned, didn't originally file.
"These companies buy patents they don't always use."
In this case "a lot" might be tens or hundreds or thousands - I just don't yet know.

I don't believe this is searchable by the USPTO or other patent sites. Changes in assignment can happen without changes to the information in those patent records. A large company may purchase a smaller one and keep the smaller companies trade name for those products. Private companies might not even report acquisitions.

@EricS although it's not what I was hoping for, that sounds like a good answer. Thanks!

Hopefully you’ll get a proper answer. For public companies I believe there are reporting requirements so you might be able to get some data on a specific company or group of companies. That sort of researching is beyond my expertise.

Often the market for patents of failed startups are NPEs.

@GeorgeWhite exit strategy ≠ failed. Not everybody thinks an IPO is a life-affirming experience. Some folks think walking away with a modest sum is much better than sticking around as things get crazy. Or perhaps I'm completely missing your point. Anyway NPE? (Non-Practicing Entity, Non- Paternity Event, Non-Person Entity, New Political Economy?)

Non practicing entity’s might be a probable buyer of patents. I agree that IPO isn’t the only exit possibility. I co-founded a company that was sold to a large semiconductor company.

@GeorgeWhite got it, thanks!

Another annoying thing - Names aren't standardized. So, the USPTO thinks "Company LLC" is different than "Company, LLC" and "Company, L.L.C.". Also, sometimes, for some reason, you will have "Company Limited" and "Company Ltd" and "Company, Ltd." all referring to the same -Company- but, with the different names, you cannot easily query the APIs for the data.
